# Reporting Crashes within an iOS Framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, crash-reports

Is there a way to configure Fabric or PLCrashReporter or any similar crash reporting framework to report crashes on a dynamic Cocoa framework that I distribute to app developers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. You can not register crash handlers that only run for a (dynamic) framework.

Comment: Can a dynamic framework depend on another dynamic framework, like Realm?

Comment: Please don't post new questions as comments and also check the Apple documentation first.